# Why do categorical predictor variables in regression need to be recoded as multiple predictors?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, scikit-learn

I'm learning about machine learning using Python's library scikit learn, and in their [tutorial here](http://scikit-learn.github.io/scikit-learn-tutorial/general_concepts.html#handling-categorical-features) they mentioned about a categorical variable `color` which can have values `purple`, `blue` and `red`.

What is the reason behind using 3 boolean variables `color#purple`, `color#blue` and `color#red` instead of having the single variable `color` but mapping the values `purple`, `blue`, `red` to `1`, `2`, `3`?

Will doing either way have any effects on the regression fitting/prediction?

Comment: Coding colours with `1`, `2` and `3` will give the interpretation that `blue` is two times larger than `purple`, and `red` is three times larger than `purple`, which usually is not a case.

Comment: Expanding on what @djhurio said, the mapping of colors to number is arbitrary, yet different mappings would give very different results. Using numbers will make the results nonsensical.

Comment: @djhurio, can you please answer the question in an answer field rather than as a comment. I see that CV has particularly many questions which are answered somewhere in comments, while I feel it would be much more effective to have a one well formed answer in a right place ;)

Comment: @sashkello, I was thinking about posting an answer, but it feels that commenting is easier. The answer should be more solid taking into account different aspects. Thanks for advise!

Comment: @djhurio, That's a good question though, so would be useful to others to have some nice explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate on the answers of our colleagues above: say you map purple, blue, red to $x = 1, 2, 3$. Say $x$ represents the colour of a hat, and $y$ sales. Then if we have a model with an intercept, call it $a$ and the coefficient of $x$, call it $b$, then we'd be saying:

$y = a + b x$

We only get to choose one $b$ here, which has to cater for all the different colours. Imagine more blue hats are sold than purple hats, and more blue are sold than red, then our model suits the purple-blue relationship ($1b<2b$), but not the blue-red relationship $2b<3b$ !

If we use dummy variables then we might have a model like:

$y = a + b_{\mathrm{red}}x_{\mathrm{red}} + b_{\mathrm{purp}} x_{\mathrm{purp}}$

And this doesn't run into the same ordering problems as the first model. Note we only need two dummy variables if there is an intercept, as this becomes the baseline for blue.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what data are represented by colours.

You can use colour as a single variable with colours expressed by numbers in regression if colours represent a scale for some data. For example, purple means wind speed 10 m/s, blue means 20 m/s, and red colour means wind speed 30 m/s. So we can say *something* (wind in example) is two times larger if the colour is blue compared if colour is purple, and so on.

The usual practice is to code each colour as a dummy (boolean) variables for a regression if quantitative comparison of colours is not possible.